# ¿Qué significa “dar el coñazo”?

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos, españa, vulgaridades, interjecciones

Una señora española exclamó:

> ¡Ay, ya estoy dando el coñazo!

Entiendo lo que significa la palabra *coño*, tanto literalmente como la interjección (y no creo que se refiera a la primera connotación). *Coñazo*, por otro lado, parece ser un aumentativo de la misma. ¿Qué sigifica esa expresión?

Sea cual fuere su significado, ¿Cómo está ligada a la palabra original (*coño*)?

Comment: De ahí la famosa pregunta: ¿Por qué cuando algo es bueno se dice que es "cojonudo" y cuando no lo es decimos que es "un coñazo"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Coño" significa vulva y "coñazo" es simplemente el aumentativo de "coño".

El uso en España de "coñazo" es coloquial:

> "Dar el coñazo" es dar la lata o dar la tabarra.
>
> "Ser un coñazo" es ser un pesado.
>
> Algo muy aburrido "es un coñazo".

"Dar el coñazo" es malsonante, por supuesto, pero no es raro el uso cariñoso en un contexto familiar o de confianza:

> El abuelito "nos da el coñazo" con sus batallitas.
>
> Los niños son muy lindos, pero también son "expertos en dar el
>   coñazo".

Además de los abuelitos y los niños, "dan típicamente el coñazo" los vendedores de seguros, los gaiteros y los evangelizadores puerta a puerta.

Mucho peor es cuando "te dan el coñazo" los vecinos (con su música) o los moralistas (con sus sermones).

En ciertos contextos, por ejemplo en situaciones formales, "dar el coñazo" adquiere connotaciones muy negativas:

> Si le estás pidiendo algo a tu jefe y te suelta "que no le des el
>   coñazo", la cosa va mal, muy mal.
>
> Si en una reunión de trabajo un colega te dice que "no le des más el
>   coñazo" con tu idea o tu opinión, la expresión es ofensiva.

En cuanto al origen de la palabra "coñazo" con el significado de "algo tedioso": proviene según fuentes poco fiables de una película muda de 1920 del cineasta Armando Flores titulada "El coñazo". Tal película, supuestamente estrenada en Barcelona en 1920 y adscrita a un género llamado porno fantástico, resultó ser tan tediosa que se convirtió en el paradigma de la pesadez. Este origen bien pudiera ser apócrifo.

Comment: Interesante orígen. Y sería realmente cómico que no fuese apócrifo.

Answer (score 3):

Para añadir información a de donde viene la expresión "qué coñazo".

Por lo que yo tengo entendido, "qué coñazo" viene de una expresión de hace varios siglos, cuando la prostitución era uno de los trabajos más extendidos entre las mujeres.

Si una prostituta tenía el coño muy grande o prestado, por haber trabajado mucho ese día, o por lo que fuera, se decía que era "un coñazo", con connotación negativa, al no poder ofrecer el placer buscado por el hombre que quisiera sus servicios; ya que en un coño grande, puede que no haya rozamiento.

Creo que no necesita más aclaración.

Comment: Podría ser verdad y todo.

Answer (score 2):

'Dar el coñazo' significa molestar, de forma insoportable.

Según la RAE hay una acepción de *coñazo* que significa 'golpe fuerte' proveniente de Venezuela, pero no estoy seguro si de ahí se puede derivar su relación con *coño*.

Comment: No, ese uso venezolano está relacionado con el español "escoñarse".

Answer (score 2):

En realidad, la expresión "dar el coñazo" no tiene relación alguna con los genitales femeninos. La filóloga Héloïse Guerrier investigó sobre el origen de varias expresiones vulgares o coloquiales del español, y descubrió que la palabra "coñazo" viene del latín "conatus" (esfuerzo), y tiene que ver con la persistencia empleada para conseguir algo.

Comment: ¡Interesante! ¿Podrías dar alguna referencia sobre dicha investigaión?

Answer (score 1):

En Venezuela puede significar pegar un golpe. "Te voy a dar tremendo coñazo si no me escuchas"

O "Vamos a caernos a coñazo" == "Vamos a caernos a golpe"